# Where to find dissertations in risk management

Tags: risk, reference-request, database

I'm looking for open databases of master's dissertations/theses in risk management & quantitative finance written by risk practitioners.
The goal is to find current research topics or problems in these fields which are relevant for the buy side.

For example: NYU has a MBA program in quantitative finance, but access to the dissertations requires login: https://guides.nyu.edu/dissertations

Comment: Try [OATD (Open Access Theses and Dissertations)](https://oatd.org). It is not specific to RM or QF but because it includes so many dissertations, it might still be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following schools have open databases for dissertations, with topics related to risk management:

- Princeton Operations Research and Financial Engineering Department

Example: [A New Generation of Risk Management System for Global FinTech Enterprises](https://dataspace.princeton.edu/handle/88435/dsp01zg64tp861)

- UC Berkeley

Example: [Essays in Risk Management and Financial Econometrics](https://escholarship.org/uc/item/77r9f9z6)

- National University of Singapore

Example: [Risk management with the LIBOR market model](https://scholarbank.nus.edu.sg/handle/10635/14215)

Another way is to google the search term `risk management master thesis filetype:pdf`, that should return the open master theses (in PDF format) related to risk management.